# Android Studio stuck on "Installing APK's" when trying to launch app, then fails

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I've recently bought a new PC. I've downloaded my project using git and started it using android studio. Now when I run the application (nothing changed to code) the process wil hang on 'Installing APK's' or 'Install'. After a minute or 5 Android studio will prompt me with a message telling me the following:
"installation failed with message null. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing."

Something to note may be that the project was already installed and working on the Android Device before (and has not been removed when first attempting the new installation)

I've checked several things already, but most importantly:

1. The application is no longer installed on my Android Device.
2. Instant run is turned off (as suggested many times on internet).
3. A new, fresh project will run fine on the Android Device (so it cannot be the device or the cable)

The gradle files are most important I guess:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "some.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to install in an emulator of actual device?

Comment: No, my hardware does not support emulating. Therefore I am stuck with the real device

Comment: Try to reset ADB. something similar happened to me once and got it fixed with ADB reset. If this doesn't work try to install the apk via ADB commandline.

Comment: Check your build tab!

Comment: I will try as soon as I have access to my pc again (had to go after posing). On anohter not tho, should a restart of Android Studio restart ADB as well? In that case I've already tried that. (otherwise I will try later)

Comment: @SaeedJoul Could you please explain what I should verify?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your ADB directory via cmd and try this

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and try running the app on Android studio. if that doesn't work, try this command from adb directory

```
adb install example.apk
```

Make sure you generate debug apk from android studio and place it in the adb directory for easier access.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error also. I tried all suggestions in SO but none of them worked. Then i noticed that i had very low storage in my actual device. After deleting some useless files it worked. Hope it works also for you.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the Developer options on your device, on your device you should see this dialog

[image]

Did you accept it?

Comment: Yes i did, sir!

Comment: Try File -> sync project with gradle file

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts in your device? Go to the device settings -> Apps> and delete for all the users if you haven't already

Comment: I have one account only.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts at what has been suggested here I've unfortunatly been unable to solve my issue. I am now using a deferent phone on which I can install the app properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when installing a flutter app from android studio.

I created a new flutter project and I found out everything works fine on the new project. So I thought something must be wrong with former project I was trying to run.

I deleted the project and cloned it again, adjusted my flutter version to the flutter version that was compatible with the project(asked the other devs working on the project) and voila, it worked.